# Why can't I access my API on another computer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, networking

I can't access my API/nodejs server [http://10.0.0.14:3000/] on another computer. If I search for [http://10.0.0.14:3000/] in the browser on my local computer the api is running on I get 'test' with statusCode 200 back. But if I try the same on another computer in the same network I get a timeout. Why does this happen?

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { parse } = require('querystring');

const HOST = '10.0.0.14';
const PORT = 3000;

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.listen(PORT, HOST,function() {
    console.log("Server is listening on port 3000...");
});
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', function(req,res) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

   // let body = req.body;
    console.log("GET ", req.body);
    res.send("test");
});
```

Comment: Probably a firewall issue.

Comment: how can I fix this?

Comment: Open the port in your firewall configuration.

Comment: Do you mean on my computer or router?

Comment: You are listening to connection coming from `10.0.0.14` only. You may want to do `const HOST = '0.0.0.0';` instead.

Comment: Do you think that someone should be able to get what you're Serving on your localhost Test Server via the World Wide Web?

Comment: this doesn't work.. if I do PORT = 80 it works

Comment: Interesting, host means you only listen request from that ip address. I'm that case I would use the default options, and focus on connecting on the client side. Your express ap is running on whatever ip your machine has.

Comment: first, you should  check if ping command transmits data successfully

Comment: are you using a virtual machine ?

Answer (score 0):

if it is windows add a rule to the firewall for incoming data for port 3000